# Changing () to [] for confidence interval in gtsummary table

Tags: r, confidence-interval, gtsummary, demographics

I am making my demographics table using gtsummary.
I want the confidence interval in my table to appear between [] not ().
For example,

```
  trial %>%
    select(response, grade) %>%
    tbl_summary(statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}%",
                missing = "no") %>%
    modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
    add_ci()
```

This produces:

[image]

I appreciate your help

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example (aka a reprex): something we can run on our machines. The gtsummary pkg comes with a data frame called 'trial'. The code you've provided does not create a table with a confidence interval, so I am not sure what table you're trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a mistake
I want the IQR to appear between []

Here is an example.

```
library(gtsummary)
data=colon
tbl_summary(data=colon, by=rx, missing='no')
```

[image]

for.example
nodes   2.0 (1.0, 5.0) to 2.0 [1.0, 5.0]

Answer (score 0):

at least about the CI, you can add this to your code:

```
trial %>%
  select(response, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}%",
              missing = "no") %>%
  modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  
  add_ci(pattern = "{stat} [{ci}]")
```

[image]

As for the IQR, here is an example

```
  trial %>%
    select(age) %>%
    tbl_summary(
                statistic =  all_continuous() ~ "{mean} [{IQR}]",
                missing = "no")
```

[image]